# PHP Cannot upload file larger than 40MB

Tags: php

On my site, I'm allowing file uploads. I've successfully uploaded a 40 MB file.
But I've been trying to upload a file above 40 mb

In my php.ini, I have the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10G
post_max_size = 10G
max_execution_time = 60 
max_input_time = 10000 
memory_limit = -1
```

I work on window server.
I tried a 100mb file. It failed every time.

Comment: Are you using php > 5.1. The `G` modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using php > 5.1. The `G` modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0.

I think your php doesn't correctly parse the `G` you are using.
Try:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
post_max_size = 10000M
```

Are you sure you want to allow 10 gigabyte? Better to define something close to the max file size you are using. So if it is something like 40 megabyte use `50M`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 
**post_max_size = 10G**
Try this
**upload_max_filesize = 40M**

Don't use too big size 10G ,Try with 100M